# How to use Solr to index an entire C drive

Tags: java, windows, solr, indexing

Recently I started with Solr and I have setup Solr on a Windows 7 machine. I can use `Solr` to index folders on my pc, but also to index network shares.

The problem I have is as following:
I need to be able to index an entire c drive on a Windows server. When using `\\[servername]\c$` in the Windows explorer address bar, I can see the content.

But using the following code will not index the c drive:

```
java -Dauto -Drecursive -jar post.jar \\[Servername]\c$
```

I do not get an error message, but the indexed files is zero. It's not even working when trying to index my local c drive.

How can I index the C drive of a Windows server that is on my network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map a physical drive to the [Server]\Share and run the application on that.
You can also use the `popd` and `pushd` commands in a batch file to put you in the drive you have just mapped.

Comment: I've also run into this issue - this is definitely the way to go about it.

Comment: The mapping is done. But Nothing is indexed when I try to index the mapping. here is the post I am trying to do: C:\Users\Student\Documents\SolrIndex\solr-4.7.1\solr-4.7.1\example\exampledocs>j
ava -Dauto -Drecursive -jar post.jar Y:\

SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pp
tx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
Entering recursive mode, max depth=999, delay=0s
0 files indexed.